# Why does nest.js use a factory to specify a type rather than the class itself?

Tags: nestjs

It's common in Nest.JS to see something like this:

```
@SomeThing({ type: () => MyEntity })
class MyClass {}
```

What is the purpose of this? It can't be for preventing things from running, as its a class reference, not an instance, and the import is already run. Nor do I think it's lazy loading, as there's no lazy references to it.

So what's the reason for this pattern over, say:

```
@SomeThing({ type: MyEntity })
class MyClass {}
```

My objective is, I have a huge list of metadata that has this `type` factory as a property and I need the underlying entity it's pointing to. I want to know if there are downsides to calling the function to get the entity

e.g.

`const targetClasses = someMetadata.map(meta => meta.targetFn()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually is for lazy loading, but not necessarily for the reason you think. It's to ensure that there's no problems when it comes to circular references. If Nest just used `type: MyEntity` and `MyEntity` imported `MyClass`, then one of the two files (or possibly both of them) would have that `type` show up as `undefined`. By allowing the type to resolve lazily using a factory, it ensures that the type value is there. This also prevents overhead from remembering when to use `type: Class` vs `type: () => Class` by just unifying the API

Comment: if  `MyEntity` imports `MyClass` as per your example, and `MyClass` imports `MyEntity` to perform this decorator, is that not already a circular reference? Or is it a circular reference in something else other than imports?

Comment: It is a circular reference, but because the types are lazily evaluated rather than being evaluated at the time of file import it's not a problem. decorators normally run their related code at the time of file import, as they are essentially top level functions that get added to the bottom of each file

Comment: I guess I'm missing an understanding on the purpose of type evaluation and how nest uses it and a quick google didn't provide much. I'm failing to understand how a reference to the type avoids a circular reference, despite the fact that the imports are already circular.

Comment: So, if this factory is not here, these types show up as `undefined` because you get in this continual loop of A needs B needs A etc. Typescript jumps out of this once it detects a circular reference so the compilation still can finish. When you try to run the code, you end up getting the `undefined` type. With the factory, because it can be evaluated at a later time, the type isn't `undefined`. Nest needs this type evaluation to know how to forward it on to sub-systems (mongo, gql, and swagger for example)

Comment: When you say it's typescript. does this mean that it's not the typescript code itself that I have to worry about circular deps, but the results of the transpile? I'm struggling to see where the circular dep really is, as a class reference and a function of a class reference in regular code wouldn't make much difference afaik.  Apologies if it feels like you're talking at a brick wall, the penny doesn't seem to be dropping.

Comment: Right, it's the resultant JavaScript that you'd need to be more concerned with. Nest is a Node framework, and at the end of the day, it's `node` that is running when `nest start --watch` is used. Just having circular references isn't the end of the world, so long as when the reference is evaluated, there is a value there